# laravel 8 Sorry! You have entered invalid credentials

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I am using a custom Authentication in Laravel 8 and whenever I try to Enter a valid email/password am getting this error: Sorry! You have entered invalid credentials.

here is my code:

1#Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Session;
use App\Models\User;
use Hash;
use Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }  
      
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function registration()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }
      
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     * 
     * @return response()
     */
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

            return redirect()->intended('dashboard')
                        ->withSuccess('You have Successfully logged in');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Sorry! You have entered invalid credentials');
    }
      
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function postRegistration(Request $request)
    {  
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
           
        $data = $request->all();
        $check = $this->create($data);
         
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Great! please login.');
    }
    
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function dashboard()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return view('dashboard');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Opps! You do not have access');
    }
    
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function create(array $data)
    {
      return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
      ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function logout() {
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();
  
        return Redirect('login');
    }
}
```

2#Login.blade.php:

```
    @extends('layouts.layout')
  
@section('content')
<div class="login-form">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">Login</div>
                  <div class="card-body">

                    @if (Session::get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ Session::get('success') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
  
                      <form action="{{ route('login.post') }}" method="POST">
                          @csrf
                          <div class="form-group row">
                              <label for="email_address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Email Address</label>
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <input type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control" name="email" required />
                                  @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                  @endif
                              </div>
                          </div>
  
                          <div class="form-group row">
                              <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" required />
                                  @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                                  @endif
                              </div>
                          </div>
  
                          <div class="form-group row">
                              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                  <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label>
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
  
                          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                  Login
                              </button>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                        
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

For registration it's working fine, the only problem is in Login form. Hope you can help.

Comment: Have you confirmed the `$credentials` you're providing the `Auth::attempt` method are valid? Based on your code logic and the error you're seeing they are incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I have entered correct credentials

Comment: Where is “custom authentication” code?

Comment: Your code also looks correct to me; you're properly using `Hash::make()` when creating the User record, and passing the un-hashed `password` to `Auth::attempt()`. You'll have to do some debugging: `$user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->firstOrFail();`, then `dd(Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password));`; if any part of that code produces an error (No User found for `email`, or `false` for `Hash::check()`), then you can verify you're using the correct credentials.

Comment: @TimLewis the u code posted for testing is not working. I tried to dd the email and password whether there fetched properly from the form and it was successfully requested. not sure what am missing here :(

Comment: Its in 1#Controller. I put all my logic in this file. @Maksim

Comment: Here we go again... *"is not working"* is not helpful to me at all... What didn't work? Did you get an error? Did it return `false`? Please provide more details. If you did this code: `public function postLogin(Request $request) { $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->firstOrFail(); dd(Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)); }`, I would expect `true` as the output; what did you get?

Comment: Yes bro, now am getting False. @TimLewis

Comment: Sweet! So that means it's finding your `User` record based on the correct `email`, but failing the check for `password`. Did you try resetting your password to something simple, like `12345678`, and attempting again? For security reasons, Laravel's code will never say "Your password is wrong", as that tells the person trying to login that a User with the supplied Email exists, which makes it _much_ easier to attack the system.

Comment: I created a new user. with password 12345678. its still giving False response and wrong credentials @TimLewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step: check your user model extends from Authenticable that main user model uses,
Second step:use bcrypt instead of Hash::make,
If solutions doesnt work send your model and config/auth.php for better answer

Comment: Thanks man. You opened my eyes into the user model which was where the issue resides. I realized that I had put this function in the user model: 'public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
   $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}'. when I removed this code from the User, it worked fine with me.